# Implementing Kernel32Dll.CreateFile gives "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error

Tags: c#-2.0

We have implemented following code in our app:

'SafeFileHandle handle = Kernel32Dll.CreateFile("filepath", GenericRead, Read|Write, IntPtr.Zero, Open, None, IntPtr.Zero);

It works fine when using only one app instance, but when two app simultaneously tries to load same file, it throws
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error.

What will be appropriate use of Kernel32Dll.CreateFile in such conditions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have some mistake in our code which we had figured out. We need to put FILE_SHARE_READ rather Read|Write in file share. And there is also problem in another part of our code. Following is the working version:

SafeFileHandle handle = Kernel32Dll.CreateFile("filepath", GenericRead, FILE_SHARE_READ, IntPtr.Zero, Open, None, IntPtr.Zero);

Regards